# Biblatex: Requesting help customising for bib names uppercase

Tags: biblatex

I have been having trouble trying to figure out where to start for customising biblatex.  With so many moving parts, old docs, old answers etc it was easy for me take wrong turns such as trying to use makebst, and whilst it has been fun, I have not made as much progress as time requires and am thus asking for help here.  I am sorry if this is not a technically interesting question - I have looked at a fair bit of fine material and watched some well produced videos.  My request is in the absence of a primer, for a few pointers at to what I need to learn in order to produce a useful cfg to document and share.

As a starting point, I need author year citations, and uppercase author names in the bibliography. Once I have learnt to do those I am sure I will be able to refine the cfg to the requirements.  One conundrum that is not clear to this novice is where to start, when the required style is between other styles.

I have been navigating the answers here, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076 I have mucked about with various other answers too. I have had *a lot* of fun.

I want to produce:

Doe (2012) identified a number of ways to embolden citations but due to lack of user clue these dont appear to be effective in understanding how to do this in the bibliography.
[and]
There is a lack of skill in this user (Doe 2012).

**Refs:**
DOE, J. 2012. A macro for formatting names.

With gratitude.

```
%% kludge test MWE to 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

 \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Doe12,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = {2012},
  title = {A macro for formatting names},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}


\newbibmacro{name:newformat}{%

   \uppercase{\namepartfamily}  % this doesn't do it.
   \textbf{\namepartgiven}   % this works as intended
   }

\DeclareNameFormat{newformat}{%
  \nameparts{#1}% split the name data, will not be necessary in future versions
  \usebibmacro{name:newformat}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%

}

\DeclareNameFormat {namepartfamily}{\MakeUpperCase{#1}} %% this doesnt do make my refs uppercase
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\uppercase{#1}} %% not this either

\begin{document}

  \section*{Testing the format here}

I am autociting \autocite{Doe12}.

Whereas here \textcite{Doe12}, says that '\texbf{texbf}' does not work in the same manner as ' \uppercase{uppercase}'.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Yes, `biblatex` is indeed a bit daunting to figure out, but many things can be done simply. In this case using `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}` should work. So I think the following question is a duplicate: [Biblatex - capital names in references, regular in cites](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/154923)

Comment: Thank you. @AlanMunn \AtBeginBibliography does seem like the solution.  I am glad that I asked despite my anxieties and sad that I did indeed miss the answer and created a duplicate.  :/

Comment: Don't feel bad about not finding the duplicate. They're usually easier to find if you know the answer already. :)  And thanks for giving a minimal example document with your question.